# I want to get data from wikimedia using their REST API

Tags: javascript

Link- https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/#/

i have a search button in my program. user enters the text about which he has to search and program fetches the page from wikimedia. how can i do this in native javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This is sample code I wrote sometime ago using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

```
function fetchRandomContent() {
    fetch('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&origin=*&action=query&generator=random&rvprop=content&prop=revisions', {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        credentials: "same-origin"
    }).then(function(promise) {
        promise.json().then(function(response) {
            //--- Parsing Wikipedia data ---//
            var data = {},
                keys = Object.keys(response.query.pages),
                key = keys[0];

            data.title = response.query.pages[key].title
            data.content = response.query.pages[key].revisions[0]["*"]
            //--- Parsing Wikipedia data ---//
        });
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('shit!', error);
    });
}

fetchRandomContent();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to URL https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page for API details of wikimedia